# Redirecionamento de Página ao dar Scroll

Tags: rolamento

Boa tarde, estou precisando de algum código que permita o Redirecionamento imediato a outra página ao dar Scroll (por mínimo Scroll que seja feito, ao menor movimento mesmo). Alguém pode me dar uma dica, ainda sou meio iniciante. Grato a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Para mim isso não é uma boa pratica pois barras de rolagem são áreas laterais à janela do browser, que sinalizam a existência de conteúdo que ultrapassa a área visível da página e permitem o deslocamento da janela para alcançá-lo, ajudando a adaptar a janela ao conteúdo publicado.

**JQUERY**

> Para ser o mais rápido possível é melhor fazer logo no click pois quem vai ao Scroll a intenção é sempre rolar!

```js
var clickedOnScrollbar = function(mouseX){
  if( $(window).outerWidth() <= mouseX ){
    return true;
  }
}

$(document).mousedown(function(e){
  if( clickedOnScrollbar(e.clientX) ){
    window.location = "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/";
  }
});
```

```css
#a {
height:1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso de forma simples com JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function(){  
   location.href = "outra_pagina.html";
}
</script>
```